# Start one specific line in csv file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.4

I have a large file, and i want to start on the line where i end in the for loop.

```
def ip_to_land(whatIP, startline):

    with open("cord.csv") as csvfile:
    # 100640 total lines
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ",")

    for row in readCSV:
        IP_LOW = IPAddress(row[0])
        IP_HIGH = IPAddress(row[1])
        Land = row[2]

        start_line += 1

        if IPAddress(whatIP)>=IP_LOW and IPAddress(whatIP)<=IP_HIGH:
            return Land, row[3], row[4], start_line
            readCSV.seek(start_line)
            break
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `readCSV` is a file open for reading, not a `csv.reader` (which is not seekable), you seek to a **byte** offset, not a **line** offset.

So, use e.g

```
start_line = readCSV.tell()
```

to be able to later seek back to the same spot.

A file's `tell` method returns the offset in bytes at which you're about to read.  As the docs at https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html say, if you're on Windows, you may need to open the file in mode `rb` (read binary) to ensure `tell` and `seek` work as desired (otherwise there may be line-ending conversions that stand in the way of proper operation).

Comment: I have added the real code up top. Is it still possible ?

Comment: Hard to tell due to indent problems -- please edit your Q, indenting by four spaces, not a tab.  Where exactly are the `seek` and the `break`, and **why**, is pretty mysterious as of now.  In general, it is possible, but the offset in bytes (which still is where you can seek to) and the current line number (not useful for seeking), if the latter is needed for different purposes, must be maintained separately.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I am assuming readCSV is a list of all the lines of the file.

```
    readCSV= open('filename.CSV').readlines() #list of all the lines in file

    for row in range(len(readCSV)):

        if something:
            #your code
            break

    print readCSV[row+1]
```

If `row` was say 33 when you exit the loop, the `print` call will print the next line in the list of lines.